# Add HashMap values in HashMap inside ArrayList without duplicate in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, duplicates

Set of values present in `HashMap<key,value>`. How to add `HashMap` value in `HashMap<key,value>` inside `ArrayList` by avoiding duplicate value in `android`.

Comment: Post some code please , the question is very poor

Comment: provide an example or code

Comment: Have a look at the answer if it sufficient for your issue

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean adding unique values from `HashMap` to `ArrayList` ?

If yes, you can add HashMap entries `<K, V>` to a reverse HashMap `<V, K>`, then get all the keys of this reverse map. Assume that your key has class type `K` and your value has class type `V`:

```
// change to private if needed
public List<V> getUniqueValues(Map<K, V> originMap) {

    Map<V, K> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();
    Set<K> keys = originMap.keySet();
    Iterator<K> iterator = keys.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        K key = iterator.next();
        V val = originMap.get(key);
        reverseMap.add(val, key);
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(reverseMap.keySet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add HashMap values inside array list use this approach:

**Firstly declare it as below to flexibly add the values directly as a** `ArrayList`
`ArrayList<HashMap<key,value>>> myArrayHash = new ArrayList<HashMap<key,value>>`

**To add values into it:**
If you have already created your HashMap from the sound of your question:
`myArrayHash.add(HashMapValue);`

**To avoid the duplicates:**
You need to use the `Set Class` in java so finally the code would amount as below:

`Set<ArrayList<HashMap<key,value>>> hashset = new HashSet<>();
hashset.addAll(myArrayHash);
myArrayHash.clear();
myArrayHash.addAll(hashset);`

You will need to replace your variable values appropriately since you havent posted any code. This is good enough example to set you up for a general example for any sort of such issues in future.

Comment: while adding hashset in myArrayHash it shows error (The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>)).